# where can I modify the web.config file of a WebGL game made in unity 3d

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a problem embedding my WebGL game made in unity as it uses Jsons to store user data. The problem is explained in more detail here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1334307/unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-jso.html

The solution to this problem involves changing a web.config file but I do not know what this is or how to modify it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I am providing a WebGL file to be embedded in a separate party's website which as far as I am aware uses shopware

Comment: The web.config file is normally located in folder that serves as document root for the website. If you're using Visual Studio it is also normally visible in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information as to where you are trying to embed the game?

Comment: @PeterMeadley I will update my original post

Comment: @RaZ in that case you will need to get in touch with the separate party. The config file will only be accessible to the website administrators themselves. Unfortunately you won't be able to do anything else on your end.

Comment: @PeterMeadley thanks for your help:-)

Comment: @PeterMeadley I have just read a post stating that the web.config file has to placed into the build folder of the webgl game... In this case how would I create this web.config file?